# How to add 'selected ' Attribute when adding options using jquery at any position

Tags: jquery

e.g.I want to add 'selected' attribute at the third position.
Can you explain if I can add selected attribute in append() of jquery.

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{ 
     if(i==3)
     {
       $('#mySelect').append($('<option>',
       {
          value: i,
          text :i
      }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please considering accept **Rory McCrossan**'s answer and my apologize for the misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Correct the answer as per **Rory McCrossan**'s comment(added `append()` with jQuery object), and apologize for misleading.

The issue is about the `if` statement, your code would only append one `<option>` that is if `i` equals 3.

[jQuery API Documetation](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

According to the documentation, you have several options to do so...

1) Use `append()` with jQuery object

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  $('#mySelect').append($('<option>', {
    value: i,
    text: i,
    selected: i == 3 ? true : false
  }))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="mySelect"></select>
```

2) Use `appendTo()`

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  $('<option>', {
    value: i,
    text: i,
    selected: i == 3 ? true : false
  }).appendTo($('#mySelect'))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="mySelect"></select>
```

3) Use `append()` with a method

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  $('#mySelect').append(CreateOption(i))
}

function CreateOption(i) {
  return $('<option>', {
    value: i,
    text: i,
    selected: i == 3 ? true : false
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="mySelect"></select>
```

4) Use `append()` with text

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var selected = i==3 ?  ' selected=true' : ''
  var option = '<option value='+ i + selected + '>' + i + '</option>'
  $('#mySelect').append(option)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="mySelect"></select>
```

Comment: `So you can't append an element like that` Yes you can. The documentation even says so, but you conveniently missed out that part. `Content: DOM element, text node, array of elements and text nodes, HTML string, or **jQuery object** to insert`. Your second method is event doing this, just in a more obfuscated manner. In fact, I'm not sure how this is an accepted answer as what the [OP has already works](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/8xqt8Lu3/). This is just a regurgitation of the documentation. Please consider the accuracy of your answers before potentially mis-leading new visitors.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You're right, seems I have misleading some of the users and visitors, I'll correct the answer and please take a look if there's anything wrong. Thanks for your point out and apologize for the mistake I done.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
$('#mySelect :nth-child(3)').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because of your nested `if` statement, which results in only the `option` with a value of `3` being appended to the `select`.

To fix this you can append all the `option` elements together, then set the `val()` of `select` to choose the specific one you want. Try this:

```js
var html = [];
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  html.push($('<option>', {
    value: i,
    text: i
  }));
}

$('#mySelect').append(html).val(3);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect"></select>
```